# Biggest/smallest bean cup algorithm in C - easy game

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I'm doing a mini project for school, the game consists of an even set of cups, X, each one with x1, x2,... beans inside each cup. There are two players, Bella and Alex. 
Alex always takes the cup with more beans. Bella, in her first play takes the one with less beans, the second play takes the cup with more beans, the third with less beans, and so on....
They can just grab the first or the last cup of the set. Alex always starts first. Whoever gets the most beans win.

```
For Example: X = 4, with x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3, x4 = 4.
Alex takes x4, A = 4. 
-> X = 3, with x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3.
Bella takes x1 = 1, B = 1. (first play, takes the smallest)
-> X = 2, with  x1 = 2, x2 = 3.
Alex takes x2, A = 4 +3 = 7.
-> X = 1, with  x1 = 2.
Bella takes x1, B = 1+2 = 3.
```

So, Alex wins with 7 beans against Bella's 3 beans.

I've the code here, everything's fine but on the second play of Alex, he gets 8 instead of 7. Can you help me? The montinhos[] represents the array x1, x2, x3, x4...

Thanks.
PS - gcc option is: gcc -std=c99 -Wall $file -lm

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i, j, z, n, A, B, jogada = 1;
void alex(int *n, int montinhos[]);
void bella(int *n, int montinhos[]);

int main(void)
{

do
{
  printf("Number of cups: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
} while(n < 2 || n > 100 || n % 2 != 0);

int montinhos[n];

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    scanf("%d", &montinhos[i]);

for (j = 0; j < n / 2; ++j)
{ //play while there are cups
  alex(&n, montinhos);
  printf("Temp Alex %d\n", A);
  bella(&n, montinhos);
  printf("Temp Bella %d\n", B);
}

if (A > B)
{
  printf("Alex wins with %d against %d\n", A, B);
}
else if (B < A)
{
  printf("Bella wins with  %d against %d\n", B, A);
}
else
{
  printf("Alex e Bella tie with %d\n", A);
}

return 0;
}


void bella(int *n, int montinhos[])
{
  if (*n==1) //if there's only 1 cup
  {
    B += montinhos[0];
    *n--;
  }
  else if (jogada % 2 != 0) //first/uneven play - takes the smallest cup
  {
    if(montinhos[0] < montinhos[*n - 1])
    {
      B += montinhos[0];
      for (z = 0; z < *n - 1; ++z)
           montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
      *n--;
    }
    else if(montinhos[0] > montinhos[*n - 1])
    {
      B += montinhos[*n - 1];
      for (z = *n - 1; z < *n - 1; ++z)
           montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
      *n--;
    }
  }
  else //if second/.../even play, takes the biggest cup
  {
    if(montinhos[0] > montinhos[*n - 1])
    {
      B += montinhos[0];
      for (z = 0; z < *n - 1; ++z)
           montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
      *n--;
    }
    else if(montinhos[0] < montinhos[*n - 1])
    {
      B += montinhos[*n - 1];
      for (z = *n - 1; z < *n - 1; ++z)
           montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
      *n--;
    }
  }
}



void alex(int *n, int montinhos[])
{
  //if left cup is bigger
  if(montinhos[0] > montinhos[*n - 1])
  {
    A += montinhos[0];
    for (z = 0; z < *n - 1; ++z)
         montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
    *n--;

  }
  else if (montinhos[0] < montinhos[*n - 1])
  {
    A += montinhos[*n - 1];
    for (z = *n - 1; z < *n - 1; ++z)
         montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
    *n--;
  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome, Pat. Because you have a problem with your code, you are asking at the correct site. But, since you are new, I will inform you that when your code is complete and tested, you can post it at our [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) sister site and get feedback on how you might improve it. It can be very helpful.

Comment: @Mawg The programming problem is not being asked for a review, and the question is written in a less-than-easy-to-read manner, but he has a programming problem.  __Alex gets 8 instead of 7__

Comment: Sorry, no offence in tended, buy I can't see what you are trying to tell me. I am well aware that the program is not presented for review. As I stated, since as the program is not working then this is the site to ask about it. However, I see no harm in pointing out a sister site - and when to use it - to a new user. Btw, thanks a 1,000,000 for cPanel :-)

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c99` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your code again, I realized that your variables are all globals (bad style, but not a bug).
Summary of changes:

- Because `n` is a global variable, it doesn't need to be passed as a parameter to functions.   I removed the parameter from functions `bella` and `alex`.
- Your loop to count the number of cups remaining was wrong.  It was based on `j < n/2`.  I changed it to just `while(n)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i, j, z, n, A, B, jogada = 1;
void alex(int montinhos[]);
void bella(int montinhos[]);

int main(void)
{
    do
    {
        printf("Number of cups: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while(n < 2 || n > 100 || n % 2 != 0);

    int montinhos[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%d", &montinhos[i]);

    while(n)
    { //play while there are cups
      alex(montinhos);
      printf("Temp Alex %d\n", A);
      bella(montinhos);
      printf("Temp Bella %d\n", B);
    }

    if (A > B)
    {
        printf("Alex wins with %d against %d\n", A, B);
    }
    else if (B < A)
    {
        printf("Bella wins with  %d against %d\n", B, A);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Alex e Bella tie with %d\n", A);
    }

    return 0;
}

void bella(int montinhos[])
{
  if (n==1) //if there's only 1 cup
  {
    B += montinhos[0];
    n--;
  }
  else if (jogada % 2 != 0) //first/uneven play - takes the smallest cup
  {
    if(montinhos[0] < montinhos[n - 1])
    {
      B += montinhos[0];
      for (z = 0; z < n - 1; ++z)
           montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
      n--;
    }
    else if(montinhos[0] > montinhos[n - 1])
    {
      B += montinhos[n - 1];
      for (z = n - 1; z < n - 1; ++z)
           montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
      n--;
    }
  }
  else //if second/.../even play, takes the biggest cup
  {
    if(montinhos[0] > montinhos[n - 1])
    {
      B += montinhos[0];
      for (z = 0; z < n - 1; ++z)
           montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
      n--;
    }
    else if(montinhos[0] < montinhos[n - 1])
    {
      B += montinhos[n - 1];
      for (z = n - 1; z < n - 1; ++z)
           montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
      n--;
    }
  }
}



void alex(int montinhos[])
{
  //if left cup is bigger
  if(montinhos[0] > montinhos[n - 1])
  {
    A += montinhos[0];
    for (z = 0; z < n - 1; ++z)
         montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
    n--;

  }
  else if (montinhos[0] < montinhos[n - 1])
  {
    A += montinhos[n - 1];
    for (z = n - 1; z < n - 1; ++z)
         montinhos[z] = montinhos[z+1];
    n--;
  }

}
```

Comment: Still, that's not the problem here. I'm getting the wrong result with Alex (if the cups are 1 2 3 4) or with Bella (if the cups are 4 3 2 1)..... Btw, gcc (gcc -std=c99 -Wall $file -lm) on Quincy is getting me some errors on the *n-- lines: warning: value computed is not used